# Regular Expression to match one or more digits 1-9, one '|', one or more '*" and zero or more ','

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm new to regular expressions and I need to find a regular expression that matches one or more digits [1-9] only ONE '|' sign, one or more '*' sign and zero or more ',' sign.

The string should not contain any other characters. 
This is what I have:

```
if(this.ruleString.matches("^[1-9|*,]*$"))  
{  
    return true;  
}
```

Is it correct?
Thanks,
Vinay

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: Can you provide an example string?

Comment: I'm guessing you tested it and your question is merely a way of asking how it should look like?

Comment: Unclear.  Are you testing for the AND of these things, or the OR of them? In either case, here is a hint: some of these are special characters.

Comment: > one or more digits [1-9] only ONE '|' sign, one or more '*' sign and zero or more ',' - exactly in that order or they can be mixed?

Comment: They can be in any order and yeah I tested it and I'm not getting the right answer. The string should contain only digits from 1 - 9 AND only one | sign AND one or more * sign AND zero or more * sign

an example string would be: 1-2,4-5|3*2,2*2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should test separately for every type of symbols rather than write complex expression.

First, test that you don't have invalid symbols - `"^[0-9|*,]$"`

Then test for digits `"[1-9]"`, it should match at least one.

Then test for `"\\|"`, `"\\*"` and `"\\,"` and check the number of matches.

If all test are passed then your string is valid.

Comment: Although I generally try to answer the question as asked, +1 for pointing out that sometimes one regex simply is not the best way to go.

Comment: This is correct if the order does not matter (if not only e.g. "12|*," but also "3,|*12" should match)

Answer (score 4):

Nope,  try this:

```
"^[1-9]+\\|\\*+,*$"
```

Comment: This is correct if the parts of the string should be in the order mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Please give us at least 10 possible matching strings of what you are looking to accept, and 10 of what you want to reject, and tell us if either this have to keep some sequence or its order doesn't matter. So we can make a reliable regex.

By now, all I can offer is:

```
^[1-9]+\|{1}\*+,*$
```

This RegEx was tested against these sample strings, accepting them:

```
56421|*****,,,  
2|*********,,,  
1|*  
7|*,  
18|****  
123456789|*  
12|********,,  
1516332|**,,,  
111111|*  
6|*****,,,,
```

And it was tested against these sample strings, rejecting them:

```
10|*,  
2***525*|*****,,,  
123456,15,22*66*****4|,,,*167  
1|2*3,4,5,6*  
,*|173,  
|*,  
||12211  
12  
1|,*  
1233|54|***,,,,
```

I assume your given order is strict and all conditions apply at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the pattern you need is

n-n, one or more times seperated by commas
then a bar (|)
then n*n, one or more times seperated by commas.

Here is a regular expression for that.

```
([1-9]{1}[0-9]*\-[0-9]+){1}
(,[1-9]{1}[0-9]*\-[0-9]+)*
\|
([1-9]{1}[0-9]*\*[0-9]+){1}
(,[1-9]{1}[0-9]*\*[0-9]+)*
```

But it is so complex, and does not take into account the details, such as
for the case of n-m, you want
n less than m
(I guess).
And you likely want the same number of n-m before the bar, and x*y after the bar.

Depends whether you want to check the syntax completely or not.
(I hope you do want to.)

Since this is so complex, it should be done with a set of code instead of a single regular expression.

Comment: Please don't use `{1}`.  The only effect it has is to clutter up your regexes.

Comment: Alan, I agree. Guess I was caught up in quantifiers!

Answer (score -1):

this regex should work

```
"^[1-9\\|\\*,-]*$"
```

- Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
- Match a single character present in the list below «[1-9\|*,-]

  »

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «

  »
- A character in the range between “1” and “9” «1-9»
- A | character «\|»
- A * character «*»
- The character “,” «,»
- The character “-” «-»

Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»

Comment: This would also allow e.g. "|||||||||", the OP wants exactly 1 | and 1 0r more "*".